# How to limit access to Azure DevOps Organisation Settings and user listings?

Tags: azure-devops

We need to invite some external users from external organisations to our Azure DevOps project to do some testing. These external users should never be able to see each other since they will both be our customers and might be competitors.

We tried removing almost all permissions from demo external account but they still seem to see all the users even via Organisation Settings page.

Expected: 
Users should only see other users in project they work in, not the entire organisation.

How can we prevent invited users from seeing users from projects outside their own project? Or at least how can we limit their access to Organisation Settings page?

Comment: Can't you just add them to the project as member of the team only? And have a user group with them in devops that have basically no privileges.

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes I’ve done that already, they still can see a list of all uses in organization settings page.

Comment: [Eslam Badawy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/740452) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69136866) saying "they finally made it, here is the solution [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/limit-user-visibility-and-collaboration-to-specific-projects/](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/limit-user-visibility-and-collaboration-to-specific-projects/)"

Comment: There is still this issue "Note that the current restrictions are on the user interface only; users will still be able to use the REST APIs to produce or construe the restricted data." if that matters or the information is very confidential.